# if/else type statements within java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to determine upon startup whether the in-app has been purchased, this is my current code;

```
if (!(getSharedPreferences("purchased", 0).getBoolean("purchased", false)))
admob();        
Log.d("NOT UPGRADED", "SHOW AD AS UPGRADED ALREADY");
if (!(getSharedPreferences("purchased", 0).getBoolean("purchased", true)))
admobskip();    
Log.d("UPGRADED", "DO NOT SHOW AD AS UPGRADED ALREADY");
```

But it appears to run through all that code, rather than checking, with iOS I use if / else , however I seem unable to use that and wanted the java equivelent for this piece of code if possible? I have swapped the purchased to '`true`' on the second half of statement.

Comment: Less idiosyncratic indentation would certainly help us, and probably, in time, you as well.

Comment: Note that your `Log.d` statements are not part of the if statements, so they are always executed.

Comment: Always use braces and you will figure out what the issue is

Comment: use `{ ... }` scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead

```
if (getSharedPreferences("purchased", 0).getBoolean("purchased",false) == false) {
   admob();        
   Log.d("NOT UPGRADED", "SHOW AD AS UPGRADED ALREADY");
} else if (getSharedPreferences("purchased", 0).getBoolean("purchased",true) == true) {
   admobskip();    
   Log.d("UPGRADED", "DO NOT SHOW AD AS UPGRADED ALREADY");
}
```

Comment: `== true` is a tautology.

Comment: @Bathsheba just to make it clear to him as he's new to Java ;)

Comment: Thank you for this, you answered without prejudice, unfortunately some of the other guys have been a bit harsh considering I am new to this, thank you once more! :)

Comment: Come on, we're a nice bunch of folk ;-)

Comment: @Hypergater I know that :) it's obvious that you're still new to Java. same thing happening to me while trying to write on Swift as I get confused with its methods and conditions. So i know that feeling ;)

Comment: @Bathsheba well I notice that too. Some folks are just as he descried. but I'm sure we don't bite :-D

Comment: If you really want a good roughing-up then dare to ask something on the C tag ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't really get the point of this. having a good knowledge about something doesn't give you the privilege to act so. That's why stackoverflow is here.. What do you think ? Good thing is I have no intention to go for C . Thanks for giving me another reason to not :)

Comment: @Alamri: Absolutely I agree. Too many folk are downvoting on the grounds of "obviousnesss". That is never a reason to downvote. And it's getting steadily worse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123949/discussion-between-alamri-and-bathsheba).

Answer (score 3):

If you only want statements to run if an `if` condition passes, then use scope blocks `{` and `}` around that code:

```
if (condition){
    /*run all these statements*/
}
```

If you don't use the braces then only the following *single* statement is part of the `if`: that's what's happening in your case.

(Personally I *always* use braces as I believe that's a clearer style, but not everyone does that).

Comment: Very helpful, thank you very much, explained well also!